# How to implement Java graph data-structure and class with restricted visibility?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, visibility, class-visibility

I am currently learning about data structures (eg LinkedList, DoublyLinkedList, ArrayList,...) and I was wondering how to implement a (not directed) graph in Java.

I was thinking about two classes: `Graph` and `Node<T>`
Each node should know to which other nodes it is connected (is a `List<Node<T>>` appropriate? What kind of List would be best?)
The `Graph` class could then provide methods like `boolean contains(T element)`

The `Node` class would have no other use so how do I restrict visibility so that only `Graph` has access?

EDIT: furthermore how can I weigh the connections between nodes? I guess I would need a completely different Implementation than mentioned above since a simple List of connected nodes would not be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A graph is an ordered pair G = (V, E) comprising a set V of vertices
>   or nodes or points together with a set E of edges or arcs or lines,
>   which are 2-element subsets

Following definition should give you a clear way to organise your graph. It consists of `Set<Node>` and `Set<Edge>` (implementation surely would be `HashSet`). `Edge` is a pair of `from` and `to` `Node`s. `Edge` can have an attribute `cost` for weighted graph. If you need undirected graph, you can store either two directed `Edge`s indicating one undirected edge or add property `undirected` to the `Edge` class.

```
public class Graph<T> {

    private Set<Node<T>> nodes;
    private Set<Edge<T>> edges;

    private class Node<T> {
        private T value;
    }

    private class Edge<T> {
        private Node<T> to;
        private Node<T> from;
        private Number cost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Node a private inner class like this:

```
public class Graph<T> {
    /* code */

    private class Node<T> {
        /* code */
    }
}
```

For link weights: instead of saving the neighbouring Nodes as a List, save them as a `HashMap<Node, Double>` which maps each node to a certain weight.

Note: this implementation would actually be a directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should learn a  thirdparty package named JGraphT, and study how it build a graph with different attributes.